# Filter rows based on conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I need to filter rows from dataframe based on multiple conditions.
Condition is after `group_by` `ID`, and `No` is not `NA` or `0`, then `Date` is latest.

Here is my data like:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(479,147,643,228,501), c(3,3,1,2,2)),
           No = c("A009145","A009146","0","A146754",NA,"A156764",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
           Date = c("2012-06-28","2020-01-10","2020-01-10","2014-11-28",NA,NA,"2019-04-13","2017-10-27","2017-12-01",NA,NA),
           point = c(25.2,31.1,31.1,21.5,18.6,18.6,27.77,18.52,18.52,26.3,26.3))

    ID        No        Date   point
1  479   A009145  2012-06-28    25.2
2  479   A009146  2020-01-10    31.1
3  479         0  2020-01-10    31.1
4  147   A146754  2014-11-28    21.5
5  147        NA          NA    18.6
6  147   A156764          NA    18.6
7  643        NA  2019-04-13    27.77
8  228        NA  2017-10-27    18.52
9  228        NA  2017-12-01    18.52
10 501        NA          NA    26.3
11 501        NA          NA    26.3
```

I want to get result like:

```
    ID        No        Date   point
2  479   A009146  2020-01-10    31.1
4  147   A146754  2014-11-28    21.5
7  643        NA  2019-04-13    27.77
9  228        NA  2017-12-01    18.52
10 501        NA          NA    26.3
11 501        NA          NA    26.3
```

For example in ID 479,

```
    ID        No        Date   point
1  479   A009145  2012-06-28    25.2 (romove because Date is not latest)
2  479   A009146  2020-01-10    31.1
3  479         0  2020-01-10    31.1 (romove because No is 0)
```

For example in ID 228, when the both of `No` is `NA`, will keep the row with latest `Date`.

```
    ID        No        Date   point
8  228        NA  2017-10-27    18.52(romove because Date is not latest)
9  228        NA  2017-12-01    18.52
```

For example in ID 501, both of `No` and `Date` is `NA`, so keep them both.

Here is my code I have tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!(No == "0" | is.na(No))) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.Date(Date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

But I got like

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID No      Date       point
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
1   147 A146754 2014-11-28  21.5
2   479 A009146 2020-01-10  31.1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code you have tried and didn’t work?

Comment: Your question is unclear. To make it clearer, you can point out to one or two example rows that you want to remove/keep, and explain why you want to remove/keep them.

Comment: Is it possible to have a case when the latest date (e.g. 2020-01-10) hast `No == 0` and there is another but not latest date (e.g. 2012-06-28) with `No == A009146`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can use `slice_max()` ordered by the following 2 variables:

1. `!(is.na(No) | No == '0')`
2. `Date`.

Note that to order by multiple variables, you need to wrap them in a data frame or tibble.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  slice_max(order_by = tibble(!(is.na(No) | No == '0'), Date),
                  by = ID)

#     ID      No       Date point
# 2  479 A009146 2020-01-10 31.10
# 4  147 A146754 2014-11-28 21.50
# 7  643    <NA> 2019-04-13 27.77
# 9  228    <NA> 2017-12-01 18.52
# 10 501    <NA>       <NA> 26.30
# 11 501    <NA>       <NA> 26.30
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the library dplyr from tidyverse

```
# filter by
cells %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(No)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(No != 0)
```

You can filter multiple conditions in a single filter using commas. It will AND all conditions.

More info in the [dplyr libray](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org).

Useful for working with spreadsheets in R / where I learnt this [link](https://nacnudus.github.io/spreadsheet-munging-strategies/).

Comment: `!No.isna()` doesn't look right for R code - are you sure you don't mean `!is.na(No)`?

Comment: Your code seems not to get the expected output.